# Value is not printed in browser

Tags: javascript, dom, input

I am new to JavaScript and I am facing a problem in document.writeln function
When I click on the submit button it doesn't print the value entered by the user in the browser, but it is getting printed on console using console.log()

what mistake should I have made ??

Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere...

Here is the code of my HTML file and js is included inside the script tag

```js
function getval() {
    var submittedvalue = document.getElementById('number');
    document.writeln(submittedvalue.value);
}
```

```html
<label for="num">Enter the number</label>
<input type="number" name="num" id="number">
<button onclick="getval()">Submit the number</button>
```

Comment: 1. don't use document.writeln

Comment: Your original code “works”: it correctly replaces the document by the input’s value in an unclosed new document stream. Inline event handlers like `onclick` are [bad practice](/q/11737873/4642212). They’re an [obsolete, cumbersome, and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way to listen for events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead.

Comment: `document.writelln` is [not recommended](/q/802854/4642212) for DOM manipulations, as it is obsolete, slow and not suitable for any evolving application. Note that this method is often misunderstood: you’re trying to manipulate the DOM, not write to the document stream. See [the documentation about the DOM API on MDN](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) and use methods and properties that aren’t discouraged.

Comment: Here's how to do this properly: https://jsfiddle.net/cn6Lumsb/

Answer (score 0):

You can use innerHTML for write the result.

```js
function getval() {
    var submittedvalue = document.getElementById('number');
    document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = submittedvalue.value;
}
```

```html
<p id="value"></p>
<label for="num">Enter the number</label>
<input type="number" name="num" id="number">
<button onclick="getval()">Submit the number</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `document.writeln` and `document.write` after the page has been loaded (or, in most cases, at all). If you use them once the page is loaded, they implicitly open the page again — wiping out all of its contents and replacing them with the new content you provide.

To add to the DOM, use [DOM methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model):

- Calling [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) or [`insertAdjacentText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentText) on an element (like `document.body`)
- Creating elements ([`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)) and using [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) on an element
- Using the newer [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) on element
- And so on (there's lots to the DOM)...

Separately, to get the value of an `input`, you use its `.value` property.

Here's your example using `insertAdjacentText`:

```js
function getval() {
    const submittedValue = document.getElementById('number').value;
    document.body.insertAdjacentText("beforeend", submittedValue);
}
```

```html
<label for="num">Enter the number</label>
<input type="number" name="num" id="number">
<button onclick="getval()">Submit the number</button>
```

Or more likely, you want to add a `p` or similar to wrap it in:

Or creating an element and appending it, so all the numbers don't join up when you use the button more than once:

```js
function getval() {
    const submittedValue = document.getElementById('number').value;
    const p = document.createElement("p");
    p.textContent = submittedValue;
    document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

```html
<label for="num">Enter the number</label>
<input type="number" name="num" id="number">
<button onclick="getval()">Submit the number</button>
```

Finally, I strongly recommend not using `onxyz`-attribute style event handlers. Instead, use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

```js
document.getElementById("the-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
    const submittedValue = document.getElementById('number').value;
    const p = document.createElement("p");
    p.textContent = submittedValue;
    document.body.appendChild(p);
});
```

```html
<label for="num">Enter the number</label>
<input type="number" name="num" id="number">
<button id="the-button">Submit the number</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

don't  use document.writeln or document.write in your code because first it override your document and secundo it is used to inject script in web page exemple :

document.write('put a script tag with somme js code')

instead use dom methodes as innerHTML(if is html content) or innerText(if it is just a plain text)or console.log() or an alert

```
    <p id="value"></p>
<label for="num">Enter the number</label>
<input type="number" name="num" id="number">
<button onclick="document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = document.getElementById('number').value">
    innerhtml</button>
<button onclick="console.log(document.getElementById('number').value)"> console</button>
<button onclick="alert(document.getElementById('number').value)">alert</button>
```

use f12 to see the console